# What is the correct way to test classes in Python?

Tags: python, unit-tests

There is a class named `State` that has several attributes, which I need to write unit tests for. The test will need to have certain actions that change attribute values of the `State` instance. Expected parameters are located inside of the dictionary. The unit test will compare the attributes of the `State` instance with the values of the dictionary for equality.

The question is what is the best place to keep the comparison logic at? I
was thinking about 2 options:

1. Add `__eq__` method to the `State` class that contains comparison logic.
2. Add helper function inside of the test module that contains comparison logic.

Which one of the options is better and why?

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are fine.

I would recommend if you imagined how things would be if you were writing the State class driven by the tests, rather than having the tests afterward: Which option would you pick? Would you design the class so that it clients would be accessing its attributes, rather than sending messages through its methods?

If the answers are not obvious, re-writting State driven by tests may give you insights about how to better design it.